# Matching strings in arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays which checks if there is a match between them both then inserts yes into a database depending if it a match. One of the array takes 3 elements at a time, to compare against another elements that are static.

The problem in the code is that it is comparing majority correctly but I have a closer look in the database. A couple of comparisons are incorrect. Is there a better way to construct my code so nothing is compared in incorrectly?

I find the miss matches happen when the two element beside each other in $team_squad are both suppose to be 'yes'.

The string are defiantly correct as well.

**Here is a simple version of the code**

```
<php

//Take 3 subs at a time 3 home and 3 away players
for($subs = 3;$subs<=$count_subs;$subs+=3){

//Set the answers for each player to 'no' (the for loop sets all players to no).
for($data=0; $data<$squad_length; $data++){
    $input[$data] = 'no';
}

//Select 3 subs home and away for each team, starting from 0 and restrict to 3 and move up by 3's.
$h_subs_name = array_slice($home_subs_name,$subs-3, $subs);
$a_subs_name = array_slice($away_subs_name,$subs-3, $subs);

//Identify the matches from the players in the team squad with the subs 
$subshome = array_intersect($team_squad, $h_subs_name);
$subsaway = array_intersect($team_squad, $a_subs_name);

//if array is not empty run code
if(!empty($subshome)){
//For each match in the change the 'no' to a 'yes' from the forloop.
    foreach ($subshome as $key => $value) {
    # code...

    //Select the index to change to a yes
        $input[$key] = $y;

    }
}

//if array is not empty run code
if(!empty($subsaway)){
//For each match in the change the 'no' to a 'yes' from the forloop.
    foreach ($subsaway as $k => $eachplayer) {
    # code...

//Select the index to change to a yes
        $input[$k] = $y;
    }
}

foreach ($input as $s) {
$inserttablesub[] = '"'. $s . '"';
}

$querysub = 'INSERT INTO '.$subtable.' '.'('. implode(',', $players_name_insert).') '.'VALUES'.'(' . implode(',', $inserttablesub) . ')';

mysql_query($querysub) 
    or die(mysql_error());

unset($subshome);
unset($subsaway);
unset($input);
unset($inserttablesub);
}

?>
```

team_squad are used as column names in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function called array_search, looks for a match in an array and returns the key number.

```
$key = array_search($a_subs_name[$c], $team_squad);
```

Here is the documentation [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search).

Answer (score 0):

`team_squad` and `a_subs_name` should be variable `$team_squad` and `$a_subs_name`

You can use `in_array()` function

Ref: https://www.php.net/in_array

Comment: No, I'm trying to insert yes or no in each cell of the database.  Not search for only one element

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try [array_interset()](https://www.php.net/array_intersect)

This will find the common element between 2 arrays and you can use the array for insert query'

```
$team_squad = array("Wojciech Szczesny", "Per Mertesacker","Olivier Giroud","Laurent Koscielny","Bacary Sagna","Mesut Ã–zil","Aaron Ramsey","Kieran Gibbs","Santi Cazorla","Jack Wilshere","Bacary Sagna","Nacho Monreal","Thomas Vermaelen");    

$a_subs_name = array("Carl Jenkinson","Santi Cazorla","Lukas Podolski","Darren Bent","Alexander Kacaniklic","Giorgos Karagounis","Mathieu Flamini","Nacho Monreal","Bacary Sagna");

$result = array_intersect($team_squad, $a_subs_name);
```

Comment: I thought this will be a good idea but it seems to be working for the first and second row of my data

Comment: Row ? Did not get it could you please explain a bit ?

Comment: I'm scraping data from a website of players names and only want to store the players that are in the team_squad. I used the array_intersect but only got me so far. I re-post the code in more detail, just re posted code